# Add values of object properties in PowerShell without accessing each property by name

Tags: powershell, properties

I have an API that returns exit codes of script runs. I save the return object in a variable called $exitCodes.

```
$exitCodes
```

will yield an object like this:

```
@{success=12; error=1; warning=0; unknown=0}
```

My goal is to be able to tally up the values of each property of $exitCodes without doing something like this:

```
if ($exitCodes.success + $exitCodes.error + $exitCodes.warning + $exitCodes.unknown -gt 0)
{
    do something
}
```

Is there a way to get the values of each property and add them together without calling each property by name? For this example, assume that every property is going to have a value of the same type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are two ways to do it off the top of my head:

```
$exitCodes = @{success=12; error=1; warning=0; unknown=0}

$i = 0; $exitCodes.Values | ForEach-Object {$i += $_}; $i

($exitCodes.Values | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum
```

If `$exitCodes` is actually an object and not a hashtable (edit: looks like that actually is the case, just by how you addressed the properties), try something similar by enumerating the properties using the hidden `.psobject` property.

```
$exitCodes = [pscustomobject]@{success=12; error=1; warning=0; unknown=0}

($exitCodes.psobject.Properties.Name | ForEach-Object { $exitCodes.$_ } | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum

#or use $i += etc.
```

If `$exitCodes` has a lot of additional properties, you can also filter based on additional info returned by `.psobject`. Example:

```
($exitCodes.psobject.Properties | Where-Object {$_.MemberType -eq 'NoteProperty'}).Name
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, the second example worked perfect. Thanks!